# MongoDB error: uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list :

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongodb database and I find it complecated. I have books table, and I want to count all books published after 2009, and I'm getting this error message:

> uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Here is my query:

```
db.books.aggregate( [ {$match: {"books.year":{$gt: 2009}}},
   { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }] )
```

Comment: 1. The `"books.year"` filter should be in a `$match` stage. 2. In the last line, there is an opening bracket `[` before closing bracket `]`.

Comment: While I'm not familiar with how to use mongodb,  what I do notice is the errant ```[``` on the first line.  I'm not sure if that needs a closing ```]``` or it shouldn't be there?  or perhaps the last line's ```[]``` is supposed to be ```]```?

Comment: @YongShun please see my updated query, now if I run it I'm not getting either error message or results

Comment: Keep your code clean and readable (like the answer below), it will be way easier for you to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got some syntax error in your query. To modify, it should be:

```
db.books.aggregate( [ 
  {
    "$match": {
      "year": {"$gt": 2009}
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": { 
      "_id": <field that you want to group by, for example "$genre" or "$year">, 
      "count": { "$sum": 1 } }
  }
])
```